# css menu border animation not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have one problem. we make one menu bar with line animation on hover effect but this animation not proper work in safari 5.1.7 and also some error on chrome web browser, like when we hover any link forth menu line is blink also some tiny 1px with white color dot is also there:-

Html Code:-

```
<nav id="bannerNav">
 <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="who-we-are.html"><span>Menu Bar 1</span> <b></b></a></li>
    <li><a href="our-group-companies.html"><span>Menu Bar 2</span> <b></b></a></li>
    <li><a href="annual-report.html"><span>Menu Bar 3</span> <b></b></a></li>
    <li><a href="social-responsibility.html"><span>Menu Bar 4</span> <b></b></a></li>
    <li><a href="media-news.html"><span>Menu Bar 5</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Css code:-

```
body{background-color: #000000;}
#bannerNav{margin-top: 26px; float: right;}
#bannerNav ul{float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 17px;}
#bannerNav ul li{float: left; margin: 0; position: relative; list-style: none; }
#bannerNav ul li a{color: #ffffff; padding: 7px 10px; border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0); margin-left: -3px;}
#bannerNav ul li b{background: #fff;  color: #fff;  height: 15px; right:0px; position: absolute; top: 9px; width: 1px;}
#bannerNav ul li:hover b, #bannerNav ul li.active b{display: none;}
```

please see full working code here:- [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67u6hhbt/)

Comment: Out of interest, how comes your still supporting `Safari 5.1.7` when its 5 years old?

Comment: Seriously, no-one is using Safari 5...it's effectively a dead browser like IE5

Comment: oky, thanks but in chrome web browser error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `backface-visibility` to line `#bannerNav ul li a` and will be fixed at Chrome, this the line edited:

```
#bannerNav ul li a{color: #ffffff; padding: 7px 10px; border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0); margin-left: -3px;backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: yes blink error is reslove, but white dot is still there, any idea? how to remove?

Comment: i'll check  and see how can help

Comment: I fix dot issue by change font-size 16px

Answer (score 0):

Copy these css in your code it will work fine.

```
#bannerNav a:before {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY (0%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY (0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY (0%);
    -o-transform: translateY (0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 1px;
}
#bannerNav a:after {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY (0%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY (0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY (0%);
    -o-transform: translateY (0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Replace these classes in your css code everything is working fine without increase font-size.